# Realizar un Guard para validar campos en Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, guards

Tengo un código que hace un login, el login hace referencia al formulario "persona", solamente accede si el token es válido.
Pero lo que necesito hacer es un guardian el cual va actuar despues de hacer login, este va a validar que mi formulario este correcto, es decir que la informacion de mi formulario sea correcta.
La información la recupera de una API, y los datos que acepta tienen ciertas validaciones, y alguno campos son obligatorios.

Necesito que mi guardian verifique que las validaciones sean correctas y no falte ningun dato obligatorio, si es que falta al menos uno, me debe enviar al formulario "persona" para corregirlo, de lo contrario, si no encuentra que falte ninguna validación, o ningún campo, me debe redireccionar a "completo".

No se si realmente se pueda lograr eso, pero así me lo solicitaron, les compartire lo que creo apropiado.

de esta manera hago el login

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { sha256 } from 'js-sha256';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthGuard } from '../guards/auth.guard.';
import { PersonGuard } from '../guards/person.guard';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {
  correoElectronico!: string;
  clavePrivada!: string;
  idAplicacion!: string;
  form!: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private authGuard: AuthGuard,
    private personGuard: PersonGuard,
    
  ) {
    this.buildForm();
  }

  login() {
    const url = 'miruta';
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'x-client-id': 'mitoken'
    });

    const hashedClavePrivada = sha256(this.clavePrivada);
    const body = {
      correo_electronico: this.correoElectronico,
    };

    this.http.post(url, body, { headers }).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        localStorage.setItem('token', (response as any)['X_TOKEN_ACCOUNT']);
        
        if (this.authGuard.canActivate() && this.personGuard.canActivate()) {
          this.router.navigate(['/completo']);
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }

  private buildForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      correoElectronico: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      clavePrivada: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
}
```

Guardian de mi login

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(): boolean {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

en mi app-routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'persona', component: PersonaComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'completo', component: CompletoComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
];
```

algunas de mis validaciones, y tambien se ven cuales son las que son requeridas:

```
private buildForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      nombre: ['', [Validators.pattern(/^[a-z\s\u00E0-\u00FC\u00f1 ]*$/i), Validators.required]],
      primer_apellido: ['', [Validators.pattern(/^[a-z\s\u00E0-\u00FC\u00f1 ]*$/i), Validators.required]],
      segundo_apellido: ['', Validators.pattern(/^[a-z\s\u00E0-\u00FC\u00f1 ]*$/i)],
      clave_privada: ['', Validators.required],
      nuevaclave: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()\-_=+{};:,<.>]).*$/)]],
      nuevaclave_confirmar: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()\-_=+{};:,<.>]).*$/)]],
    }, {
      validators: this.passwordsMatchValidator
    });

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.formValid = this.form.valid;
    });
  }
```

y no se si sirva, pero de esta manera obtengo los datos de mi API y los muestro en los campos correspondientes en mi formulario:

```
async getUserData() {
    try {
      this.userData = await this.userService.getUserData();
      if (this.userData && this.userData.persona) {
        this.form.patchValue({
          nombre: this.userData.persona.nombre,
          primer_apellido: this.userData.persona.primer_apellido,
          segundo_apellido: this.userData.persona.segundo_apellido,
        });
      }

      console.log('this.userData2', this.userData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Y SEGÚN YO ESTO TENGO HECHO DE MI GUARD DE LO QUE NECESITO

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PersonGuard implements CanActivate {
  form!: FormGroup;
  

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.buildForm();
  }
  
  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (this.form.valid && !this.hasEmptyRequiredFields()) {
      return true; 
    } else {
      if (!this.form.valid) {
        this.router.navigate(['/completo']);
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/persona']); 
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  private buildForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      nombre: ['', [Validators.pattern(/^[a-z\s\u00E0-\u00FC\u00f1 ]*$/i), Validators.required]],
      primer_apellido: ['', [Validators.pattern(/^[a-z\s\u00E0-\u00FC\u00f1 ]*$/i), Validators.required]],
      nup: ['', [Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/), Validators.maxLength(15)]],
      nue: ['', [Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/), Validators.maxLength(15), Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  private hasEmptyRequiredFields(): boolean {
    const controls = this.form.controls;
    for (const controlName in controls) {
      if (controls.hasOwnProperty(controlName)) {
        const control = controls[controlName];
        console.log('Control:', controlName);
        console.log('Control value:', control.value);
        console.log('Control errors:', control.errors);
        if (control.errors && control.errors['required'] && control.value === '') {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Los requests Http van en un servicio, el hash de la contraseña en el backend y el Guard solamente es para verificar si es válido o no, no se que porque tienes un `FormGroup`, en este caso deberías de hacer otro componente para que el Guard permita el acceso. Probablemente necesites otro servicio para el Guard, pero primero hay que ajustar como está diseñado el código. [Communicating with backend services using HTTP](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: 1. Me comentaron que no necesitaba crear services
2. No me dieron acceso al backed
3. FormGroup es parte de mi formulario para recuadar la información

Comment: Meter los requests Http en un servicio es parte de las buenas prácticas de Angular, en la documentación viene así y es como se recomienda hacer. No entiendo de donde vas a sacar la información para rellenar un form dentro de un Guard, un Guard es como un middleware, el formGroup no sirve ni hace nada ahí ¿donde vas a ingresar los datos?, el primer guard que tienes está bien y algo así debería de ser el segundo. Puedes hacer algo parecido a lo del Token almacenando un valor que sea el que lea el guard para permitir acceso o no.